# can value() or constant() be used inside each other in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constants

I have a `.constant()` defined that acts as the base URL for a service to access. I then have several constants with relative URL paths that I'd like to prepend the base URL on to make them absolute.

Is it possible to access a `.constant()` or `.value()` from within another constant or value?

```
angular.module('App')
    .constant('baseurl', 'http://www.example.com')
    .constant('posturl', baseurl + '/posts')
```

Comment: if intending on have numerous constants, a constant can be object also. Makes it less hassle injecting one thing as dependency instead of numerous individuals

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to do something like this:

```
var baseurl = 'http://www.example.com';

angular.module('App')
    .constant('baseurl', baseurl)
    .constant('posturl', baseurl + '/posts')
```

I often have constants in a separate file, so using proper scoping (for instance, wrapping it in a self-running function) this will not pollute the app with a lot of global variables.